# mpi: send asynchronous e blocking?

Tags: multithreading, mpi

I'm studying mpi and i read that the standard mode is asynchronous and blocking. But i don't understand how does it works.
If it is asynchronous, how can it be also blocking?
If a process calls "send" and then do other stuff, why it is blocking?

Comment: That's just wrong or at the very least imprecise. Where did you read that? I recommend instead reading section 3.4 of [the official MPI specification](https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf).

Comment: `MPI_SSend()` is a synchronous and blocking send. `MPI_Send()` is a blocking send but is not a synchronous one. as @Zulan pointed, you should read (again) that chapter since in MPI non synchronous is likely not to mean what you expect.